# What purpose does using exec in docker entrypoint scripts serve?

Tags: bash, docker

For example in the redis official image:

https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/master/2.8/docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ "$1" = 'redis-server' ]; then
    chown -R redis .
    exec gosu redis "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

Why not just run the commands as usual without exec preceding them?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As @Peter Lyons says, using `exec` will replace the parent process, rather than have two processes running.

This is important in Docker for signals to be proxied correctly. For example, if Redis was started without `exec`, it will not receive a `SIGTERM` upon `docker stop` and will not get a chance to shutdown cleanly. In some cases, this can lead to data loss or zombie processes.

If you do start child processes (i.e. don't use `exec`), the parent process becomes responsible for handling and forwarding signals as appropriate. This is one of the reasons it's best to use `supervisord` or similar when running multiple processes in a container, as it will forward signals appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the additional insight in relation to docker!

Comment: This is quite important.

Comment: @adrianmouat What will be in windows container replacement for `exit "$@"`?

Comment: @kat1330 do you mean `exec "$@"`? I don't have much experience with windows containers - I guess you could take a look at powershell, but I think it might work as is, if you can use WSL in a container?

Comment: I'm confused, if parent process is responsible for handling and forwarding signals to child processes,  then why won't redis receive a `SIGTERM` if it was started without `exec`, shouldn't the parent shell which is `PID 1` forward the signal to redis?

Comment: @oeter Basically, no.The PID 1 process - the parent shell - has to trap the signal and pass it on to any children. It won't be passed on automatically. It's fairly easy to write a test with some bash scripts to verify this behaviour.

Answer (score 27):

Without exec, the parent shell process survives and waits for the child to exit. With exec, the child process replaces the parent process entirely so when there's nothing for the parent to do after forking the child, I would consider `exec` slightly more precise/correct/efficient. In the grand scheme of things, I think it's probably safe to classify it as a minor optimization.

**without exec**

- parent shell starts
- parent shell forks child

  - child runs
  - child exits
- parent shell exits

**with exec**

- parent shell starts
- parent shell forks child, replaces itself with child
- child program runs taking over the shell's process
- child exits

Comment: So normally a new shell would be created, but exec says to just run it in the current shell?

Comment: No, there's just 1 shell, but instead of forking the child process, waiting for the child to exit, and then going "oh look I'm at the end of my script file and there's nothing left to do", then exiting, the `exec` version basically "pre-exits" the parent shell so it's already gone when the child takes over. However I'll have to defer to deeper unix devs as to the precise mechanics of this dance.

Comment: I think it's a bit more important than a "minor optimization", as the parent process is responsible for handling signals. I've written a little more in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it as an optimization like tail recursion.

If running another program is the final act of the shell script, there's not much of a need to have the shell run the program in a new process and wait for it. Using `exec`, the shell process replaces itself with the program.

In either case, the exit value of the shell script will be identical<sup>1</sup>. Whatever program originally called the shell script will see an exit value that is equal to the exit value of the exec`ed program (or 127 if the program cannot be found).

<sup>1</sup> modulo corner cases such as a program doing something different depending on the name of its parent.