# How can I make the docker container to run a script every time when the container restart?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I know I can use the dockerfile's `CMD` `RUN` and `ENTRYPOINT` commands to run a script when the container initiates, but how can I make the container run a script every time when the container restarts on failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

entrypoint runs every time a container starts, or restarts.  It's common practice to put startup configuration in a shell script that then `exec`s the application's "true" entrypoint at the end.  (See [What purpose does using exec in docker entrypoint scripts serve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255814/what-purpose-does-using-exec-in-docker-entrypoint-scripts-serve) for why `exec` is important).

Remember, docker is really just a wrapper around filesystem , process, and network namespacing.  It can't restart your container in any way other than rerunning the same process it started in the first place.

You can try it yourself with an invocation something like this:

```
docker run  -d --restart=always --entrypoint=sh alpine -c "sleep 5; echo Exiting; exit"
```

if you `docker logs -f` that container, you'll see the `Exiting` come out after every 5 seconds.  Note that the container stopping will also stop the log following though, so you'll have to run it again to see the next restart.