# Is `exec "$@"` the correct way of entrypointing a dockeimage??

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, dockerfile

I stumbled upon the fact that having an entrypoint doing `exec "$@"` allows correctly redirecting signals in a Docker container. See the following questions:

- [What does set -e and exec "$@" do for docker entrypoint scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082768/what-does-set-e-and-exec-do-for-docker-entrypoint-scripts)
- [What purpose does using exec in docker entrypoint scripts serve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255814/what-purpose-does-using-exec-in-docker-entrypoint-scripts-serve/32261019#32261019)

However, I admit not fulling grasping the idea in order to understand whether or not to override this or chain a `CMD` on it.

Let's take this example to make it more clear:

Suppose I have a node.js application I want to run.

My Dockerfile would end with something like `node index.js`.

Now, assuming the base image have already an entrypoint which is using `exec` as described in the questions linked (based on a real image I'm inheriting from):

`entrypoint.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
exec "$@"
```

So I understand the base image is doing:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

In this case I could execute my node app in two ways:

```
FROM base_with_the_entrypoint_above
... 
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "index.js"]
```

Or:

```
FROM base_with_the_entrypoint_above
... 
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Honestly, I don't understand the trade-off. Appreciate clarifications.

Comment: If your base image has an entrypoint wrapper script, setting `ENTRYPOINT` in a derived image will run _instead of_ the base image's script.  If you set `CMD`, it will be passed as arguments to the wrapper script, as described in the linked question, which is probably what you want.  `CMD` is also easier to override in a `docker run` command while still running the entrypoint wrapper's setup steps.